# How to get url to image in xcassets file

Tags: swift, image, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to add an image attachment to a local push notification. The constructor for `UNNotificationAttachment` takes a URL to the asset in question. What I can't seem to figure out is a way to get the URL to an image that is in the apps .xcassets file.

Answer (score 0):

> What I can't seem to figure out is a way to get the URL to an image that is in the apps .xcassets file.

Because there isn't one. Keep the image in your app bundle instead, or copy it to disk.